# How do I search for a question and get the most popular (by votes) and accepted answers?

Tags: support, api

My end goal is to search questions with "sum variables" in the title and tagged "PHP". I have:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=votes&accepted=True&answers=1&tagged=php&title=sum%20variables&site=stackoverflow

This gives:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "php",
        "loops",
        "sum"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 3355,
        "user_id": 337690,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 89,
        "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4e90ec5b3a37364196720ba586c5af33?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "display_name": "JM4",
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/337690/jm4"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 648,
      "accepted_answer_id": 3198551,
      "answer_count": 2,
      "score": 2,
      "last_activity_date": 1278536637,
      "creation_date": 1278534580,
      "last_edit_date": 1278536009,
      "question_id": 3198528,
      "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198528/any-other-way-to-sum-variables-using-php",
      "title": "Any &#39;other&#39; way to SUM variables using PHP?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "php",
        "arrays",
        "variables",
        "while-loop",
        "sum"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 8,
        "user_id": 1898069,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2b1f1714d72cfddfd0bc17c8e7134975?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "display_name": "user1898069",
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898069/user1898069"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 882,
      "accepted_answer_id": 13841879,
      "answer_count": 3,
      "score": 1,
      "last_activity_date": 1355324512,
      "creation_date": 1355321895,
      "question_id": 13841775,
      "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841775/sum-variables-in-an-array-using-while-loop-only-1-iteration-per-refresh-php-sql",
      "title": "Sum variables in an array using while loop only 1 iteration per refresh PHP SQL"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9891
}
```

So, the accepted answer id is 3198551. How do I get the text of that answer and the other answers in the API?

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/3198551?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

Doesn't give the text of the answer:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 75381,
        "user_id": 127724,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 100,
        "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/86b3f6d49371d625e0c916944844a678?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "display_name": "Artefacto",
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/127724/artefacto"
      },
      "is_accepted": true,
      "score": 3,
      "last_activity_date": 1278534801,
      "creation_date": 1278534801,
      "answer_id": 3198551,
      "question_id": 3198528
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9885
}
```

Also, is there a way to get the question and the answer(s) in 1 API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [a custom filter](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653) with the `question.answers` and `answer.body` (or `answer.body_markdown`) properties selected.

For example:

```
/2.2/search/advanced?accepted=True&tagged=php&title=sum variables&site=stackoverflow&filter=!5-dVQXL4-MEQxzY8uikMeLCL8GO-3y--mX0o7X
```

Which [**returns results**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&tagged=php&title=sum%20variables&filter=!5-dVQXL4-MEQxzY8uikMeLCL8GO-3y--mX0o7X&site=stackoverflow&run=true)<sup>(Scroll down as needed)</sup> like:

```js
{
    "items": [ {
        "tags": ["php", "arrays", "variables", "while-loop", "sum" ],
        "answers": [ {
            "owner": {
                "reputation": 2574,
                "display_name": "Steve&#39;s a D"
            },
            "is_accepted": false,
            "score": 0,
            "creation_date": 1355322450,
            "answer_id": 13841836,
            "question_id": 13841775,
            "body": "<p><em>The problem is the loop only does 1 iteration every..."
        },
        // etc
        ],
        "is_answered": true,
        "view_count": 883,
        "accepted_answer_id": 13841879,
        "answer_count": 3,
        "score": 1,
        "last_activity_date": 1355324512,
        "creation_date": 1355321895,
        "question_id": 13841775,
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841775/sum-variables-in-...",
        "title": "Sum variables in an array using while loop only 1 iteration per..."
    },
    // etc
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9992,
  "page": 1,
  "page_size": 30
}
```

<sup>(Note that I truncated select values to reduce horizontal scrolling.)</sup>

Comment: ok a stupid question: I can access that url in a browser but I get "400 Bad Request: Your browser send an invalid request" when accessing with curl or python.

Comment: The URL above is to the live doc page.  Did you curl the API directly ([this link](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&tagged=php&title=sum%20variables&site=stackoverflow&filter=!5-dVQXL4-MEQxzY8uikMeLCL8GO-3y--mX0o7X))?  If not, you need to.  If so, you may have tripped [API rate limiting](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), or mis URL encoded the request, or [need details of errors].